# Powershell to display all automatic services that are stopped and attempt to start those services

Tags: powershell

I want to create a PS script where it will display all the automatic services that are stopped, and will attempt to start the services afterward.

Below is the PS code. It is successfully displayed all the stopped services on remote server.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -ComputerName SERVER1, SERVER2 |`
where     {($_.startmode -like "*auto*") -and `
        ($_.state -notlike "*running*") -and `
        ($_.name -notlike "gupdate") -and `
        ($_.name -notlike "remoteregistry") -and `
        ($_.name -notlike "sppsvc") -and `
        ($_.name -notlike "lltdsvc") -and `
        ($_.name -notlike "KDService") -and `
        ($_.name -notlike "wuauserv")
        }|`

        select DisplayName,Name,StartMode,State,PSComputerName|ft -AutoSize
```

Comment: All you need to do then is pipe the results to `{ $_.StartService() }`. A little more love is needed if you want to interpret the results for display.

Comment: Consider using [Get-Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service) instead of WMI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply store the results of your query into a variable instead of selecting and displaying it, and you'd have a bunch of `win32_Service` instances that all have a `StartService()` method. It's generally a good idea to check the docs of the wmi classes you're using, most of them have methods that act on the object being represented, instead of having to pipe them around to other cmdlets like most Powershell objects:

[Win32_Service class methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-service#methods)

You'd use it like this:

```
    $services = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -ComputerName SERVER1, SERVER2 |`
    where     {($_.startmode -like "*auto*") -and `
    # [...]
    }

    $service | select DisplayName,Name,StartMode,State,PSComputerName|ft -AutoSize
    $Service | ForEach {$_.StartService()}
```

Consider also using Get-Service unless you have a requirement for using WMI. You have a couple differences but the idea is the same:

```
    $Services = Get-Service -ComputerName SERVER1,SERVER2 |`
    where     {($_.StartType -eq "Automatic") -and `
    ($_.Status -notlike "*running*") -and `
    ($_.Name -notlike "gupdate") -and `
    # ...
    }
    $Services | select Description,Name,StartType,Status,MachineName |ft -AutoSize
    $Services | Start-Service
```

Also, you could also simplify your filter a lot by using the `-notin` operator:

```
    where     {($_.startmode -like "*auto*") -and `
    ($_.state -notlike "*running*") -and `
    ($_.name -notin "gupdate","remoteregistry","sppsvc","lltdsvc","KDService","wuauserv")
    }
```